# Does a router make sense in an electron app?

Tags: electron

Just wondering if a router is needed for an Electron application.

Since the URL of an app is not shown/disclosed on an Electron application, I do not see a need for a router. Specially since you do not have access to the "reload" button.

What are your thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can reload, go back and go forward even clean history on Electron. and Routing maybe can help you to organize your work like a web page.

```
var electron = require('electron');
var window = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
window.reload();
window.webContents.goBack();
window.webContents.goForward();
window.webContents.clearHistory();
```

for more information what you can do see here: [WebContents](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#instance-methods)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. No need to download some npm package now.